# Selenium WebDriver Java - Can't click on Auto Completion

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

I can't click autoCompletion options after sending the keys to the field.
I am able to list them , identify the one I want to select , but apparently there is something wrong. Here is specifications,

I want to be able to select Location field of this webpage "https://supercareer.com/home/company" on 'Sign Up' , I select , send key , click on suggested locations , but it doesn't select option. and I don't get any Errors on Java console.

**Function that I use to select AutoComplete Function:**

public static void autoCompleteOptionSelector(String autoCompleteSearchText, String selection){

```
        WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/span[1]/input"));
        autoOptions.sendKeys(autoCompleteSearchText);


        List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tt-suggestion tt-selectable']"));
        System.out.println("Size of the AutoSuggets is = " + optionsToSelect.size());

    //I print options till match with exact option I want. and then Click
        for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect){
            System.out.println(option);
            System.out.println("Values are = " + option.getText());
            if(option.getText().equals(selection)) {
                System.out.println("Trying to select: "+ selection);
                option.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is my Main , CaseFunctions is the class of above function:**

```
WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
    CaseFunctions.autoCompleteOptionSelector("18661","White Haven, PA 18661, United States");
```

And this is my output without error , but on webpage I am not able to select.

**Console Output:**

Size of the AutoSuggets is = 5

[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (b676fd34-8272-47c7-b0bc-14aace352dd6)] -> xpath: //div[@class='tt-suggestion tt-selectable']]

Values are = White Haven, PA 18661, United States

Trying to select: White Haven, PA 18661, United States

all looks fine to me.

Comment: what is the value of the selection string?

Comment: can you be more specific?  what do you mean by selection string? I wanna click on "White Haven, PA 18661, United States" after I search on location as "18661"

Comment: public static void autoCompleteOptionSelector(String autoCompleteSearchText, String selection)                   autoCOmpleteSearchText = "18661"   and selection = "White Haven, PA 18661, United States"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things and trying some friendly suggestions of "Santhosh Kumar" (thanks anyway).

This thing solved the problem about firefox , but I still wonder why? Because for any other case , never had such problem in Firefox Driver until this Location autocomplete field.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, everything is correct except the condition inside the if. We need to use contains instead of equals. Below code might give you some idea.

```
    if(option.getText().contains(selection)) 
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to select: "+ selection);
        option.click();
        break;
    }
```

Complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/santhoshkumar/Softwares/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver2.29");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://supercareer.com/home/company");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AnonymousHeader1\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/a[1]")).click();
    WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/span[1]/input"));
    autoOptions.sendKeys("18661");


    List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tt-suggestion tt-selectable']"));
    System.out.println("Size of the AutoSuggets is = " + optionsToSelect.size());

    //I print options till match with exact option I want. and then Click
    for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect)
    {
        System.out.println(option);
        System.out.println("Values are = " + option.getText());
        if(option.getText().contains("White Haven, PA 18661, United States")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Trying to select: "+ "White Haven, PA 18661, United States");
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately , nothing changed. same situation. Looks like it is not about Equals or contains. It looks like actually clicked , but AutoCompletion suggestions doesn't appear on field. But by doing it manually , it appears. I am just trying to identify what the difference might be?

Comment: It doesn't work for FireFox for me and I can't get the reason , because everything is as it suppose to be. I will provide you a visual now. Above code was already exact code that I was using, even though I copy pasted yours: please check this link and let me know if you see any mistake.                                                                               https://evrenos-hotmail.tinytake.com/sf/MTcwMzc5M181NjYzNjQw

Comment: I tested my code for Chrome Driver and it works fine. So does yours. But somehow , eventhough in Firefox , driver clicks on Correct selection , It doesnt appear in field as selected.

Comment: it works fine for me in firefox too. I am using selenium 3.4 with latest gecko and firefox browser. Are you using latest ?

Comment: I am also using selenium 3.4 and latest gecko. I have been using Firefox 32.0 as browser , I updated that and now it is 47. But still same issue.

Comment: I did , it also did not work. but I found the problem. Actually I did not found the problem , It looks like it was a problem about capabilities , "session cannot support a capability that is requested in the desired capabilities". there was an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try clicking on the option using JavaScript executor. Please replace the code option.click() with following.

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript ("arguments [0].click ()", option);
```

Comment: may I ask , how and when should I try to click with Js? I am asking this even though it had nothing to do with my problem , because 1. wanna learn and 2. when I try to use the code you shared , after js.executeSctipt , java was underlinin "executeScript" even I imported necessary things.